# Passing multi-dimensional array increases its length when passed to PHP via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, multidimensional-array

I created two arrays in javascript, namely modules and weights. The module array contains ids of modules and weights array contain the corresponding weightages. I created a multi-dimensional array with module id as its key and corresponding weight as its value. What I have done so far

```
//module array
modules = [74,82,83]

//weight array
weights = [70,10,20]

//created array
moduleWeights = [74: 70, 82: 10, 83: 20]
```

I have created 'moduleWeights' array by the following code

```
 for(i=0;i<modules.length;i++)
   {
     moduleWeightArray[modules[i]] = weights[i]; 
   }
```

When I pass this array to PHP via AJAX, I get something like this

```
Array(
   [0] =>
   [1] =>
   [2] => 
   .
   .
   .
   [74] => 70
   .
   .
   [82] => 10
   [83] => 20  
)
```

ie the length of the array increased to 84 from 3 which is correct. Why is it happening? I pass the array in a post request like this

```
$.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'url',
                 data: {data:moduleWeightArray},
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(response)
                          {
                          } 
        })
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't even work [74: 70, 82: 10, 83: 20]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an associative *object*, not an array. When you create a Javascript array and set its index `74` to a value, there's an implied value `0` through `73` before that. That's what you're seeing. To have arbitrary key-value associations you want an object instead of an array.

```
var moduleWeights = { 74 : 70, 82 : 10, 83 : 20 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using an array. You probably have

```
moduleWeightArray = [];
```

somewhere and you should've used

```
moduleWeightArray = {};
```

The problem is that when you serialize an array it always serializes all indexes up to the biggest one (with default values `undefined`). Yet another JavaScript's weird thing. You should use an object/dictionary instead.